# LaTeX input call doesn't inherit encoding from main file

Tags: input, input-encodings

I'm including TeX files with

```
\input{file}
```

but when I compile the main file with pdflatex I get:

```
\textyen unavailable in encoding T1
```

This doesn't occur if I keep it all in one tex file, which at the top has:

```
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
```

Is there any simple way for the included tex files to inherit the use of packages that's been defined in the main file?

Comment: They do inherit commands. Are you sure that the included file is latin9  encoded?

Comment: `\textgen` is not a standard LaTeX command and is not defined by any of the packages you mention loading.

Comment: @cfr If I would have to guess I would say the the error is about `\textyen`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Your crystal ball is evidently better polished than mine ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, there is a typo in the question ([revision 3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/265914/3)). `\textgen` is actually `\textyen`.

The following document, encoded in UTF-8,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
å
\end{document}
```

generates the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \textyen unavailable in encoding T1.
```

That means, the input file of the question is very likely encoded in UTF-8.
Package `inputenc` also supports document with different encodings. The encoding can be set via `\inputencoding{...}`. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8,latin9]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
  % text is encoded in latin9
  % ...
  \inputencoding{utf8}
  \input{utf8encodedfile}
  \inputencoding{latin9}
  % back to latin9
  % ...
\end{document}
```

Encoding `utf8` is somewhat special, it needs to be loaded in the preamble first, before it can be used in the document body. This is the reason for the *two* options of package `inputenc`.

Another solutions:

- All input files are using the same encoding. This simplifies the call of package `inputenc` and maybe also the editing.
- Package `selinput` can help in selecting an encoding, when the
  files are reencoded or the encoding is not known.

Comment: This solved my problem, the files I included was in UTF-8 and I chose the solution to encode all of them in the same format, Latin9.